# Call the DayRender Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am using the `OnDayRender` event to change the **BackColor** of certain days in my Calendar. There is a **DropDownList** in my aspx page. It has Names of Conference Halls. When user select a Conference Hall Name from that list, I need to call `OnDayRender` and change the BackColor of certain days in my Calendar.

I wrote code to change `BackColor` of days in my Calendar. I tested it by hard coding a `Conference Hall Name`. but I need to set `Conference Hall Name` with `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of `DropDownList` and change `BackColor` of days in my Calendar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `DropDownList.AutoPostBack=True` and that way all controls in page will be rendered including the `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` instead of your hardcoaded conference hall name.

**EDIT:**
You will also need to set `DropDownList.AutoPostBack=True` so that when you select any item from dropdown, the page will get posted back and calander will get rendered.

Comment: I know that. but i don't know how to call `DayRender Event` with `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of `DropDownList`. because logic to change BackColor of days in my Calendar is in `DayRender` method.